# How to display and edit fractions in an MVC/Razor View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to display and edit fractions in an MVC application.  Previously in WPF I used the concept of a [converter](http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html) to take a double and format it as a fraction for the user and then take the users input and covert it back to a fraction.  What would be the best way to do this in a Razor view?

Comment: How are you trying to write them out?

Comment: How to write them out to the view and read them back onto the server is the question I am asking.  I have a fraction class that I can just write a string from to put them in the view, but reading them back isn't so clear.

Comment: did you tried @Html.Raw(Model.Field)  or just @Model.Field ?

Comment: Not really because I thought it was considered a poor practice to not let the model binder do the work.

Comment: well, at least it works. you may replace it later on, once you get a better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Admit it was harder than I thought. I'm still not sure if it's the best way to do it or not, but it works.

I defined a super simple Model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [DataType("Fraction")] //It's important to define DataType
    public double MyDouble { get; set; }
}
```

and here is my simple controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        MyModel ViewModel = new MyModel { MyDouble = 0.06 };
        return View(ViewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyModel model)
    {
        // Update db.
        // Do what you want to do.
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Index view (\Views\Home\Index.cshtml):

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.MyModel
@{ViewBag.Title = "Index";}

@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.MyDouble)
<br />
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyDouble)
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fraction_changing(hiddenFieldId, numeratorId, denominatorId) {
        var numeratorValue = document.getElementById(numeratorId).value;
        var denominatorValue = document.getElementById(denominatorId).value;
        var hiddenField = document.getElementById(hiddenFieldId);
        hiddenField.value = numeratorValue / denominatorValue;
    }
</script>
```

You will find out about the above Javascript code in just a minute.

Display Template is also so easy. I just used [Fraction class](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9078/Fraction-class-in-C) (By [Syed Mehroz Alam](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Membership/View.aspx?mid=778360)) to convert double values to Fraction.

As you know, Templates (which are Partial Views) should be placed in "DisplayTemplates" and "EditorTemplates" folders under "Views" folder. I prefer to put them in "Views\Shared\" so all other Views are able to use it.

Fraction.cshtml (\Views\Shared**DisplayTemplates\Fraction.cshtml**)

```
@using Mehroz // Fraction class lives in Mehroz namespace
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<double>
@{
    Fraction fraction = new Fraction(Model);
}
@fraction.Numerator / @fraction.Denominator
```

Let's now take a look at the tricky part, which is Edit Template.

So here is Fraction.cshtml (\Views\Shared**EditorTemplates\Fraction.cshtml**)

```
@using Mehroz
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<double>
@{
    Fraction fraction = new Fraction(Model);
    string numeratorStr = fraction.Numerator.ToString();
    string denominatorStr = fraction.Denominator.ToString();

    string unifier = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace('-', '_');
    string hiddenFieldElementId = string.Format("hiddenField{0}", unifier);
    string numeratorElementId = string.Format("numerator{0}", unifier);
    string denominatorElementId = string.Format("denominator{0}", unifier);
    string onchangingFunctionSyntax = 
        string.Format("fraction_changing('{0}', '{1}', '{2}')", 
                            hiddenFieldElementId, 
                            numeratorElementId, 
                            denominatorElementId);
}

@Html.HiddenFor(m => m, new { id = hiddenFieldElementId })

@Html.TextBox("Numerator", numeratorStr,
                        new { id = numeratorElementId, onchange = onchangingFunctionSyntax })  /
@Html.TextBox("Denominator", denominatorStr,
                        new { id = denominatorElementId, onchange = onchangingFunctionSyntax })
```

What this template really do is:

1. Converting double value (its model) to an instance of Fraction.
2. Showing numerator and denominator value of the Fraction in separate Text Input.
3. Recalculate the double value (by Javascript)

Because Javascript code needs unique Id to get an element by `document.getElementById(id)`, our Edit Template has to generate these unique IDs for related elements.

You can download the code here: http://sdrv.ms/MlyDI2

Comment: If you make a change in the input and post it back does it bind the value back to a double correctly?

Comment: I have to admit that this is certainly better than what I put together of just using a App_Code helper to put it in a string from my fraction function, and give it the appropriate name, id.... and then wrote a custom model binder to intercept the DefaultModelBinder and fill in the blanks where the fractions wouldn't bind.

Comment: @PITaylor- It works on my laptop (Win 7, ASP.NET 4, MVC 3, VS2012 SP1). [Download the code](http://sdrv.ms/MlyDI2) and test it yourself.

Comment: @PlTaylor -
By the way, If it's possible for you to change the Model, I highly recommend to use a property of `Fraction` type for your Model and let this pain go away! I always afraid of depending part of my .Net web app to a piece of Javascript. :)

Answer (score 0):

The best and cleanest way to solve your issue is to develop a **Display/Edit Template**.
Here is a nice article about it:

[Overriding DisplayFor and EditorFor to create custom outputs for MVC](http://buildstarted.com/2010/09/10/overriding-displayfor-and-editorfor-to-create-custom-outputs-for-mvc/)

Comment: That displays it, but doesn't take care of the model binding.